# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring MVC with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I created a spring mvc application using freemarker template as view part. In this tried to add a model using forms.I am also using spring security
Here is the code

### employee.ftl

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Employee</legend>
  <form name="employee" action="addEmployee" method="post">
    Firstname: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br/>
    Employee Code: <input type="text" name="employeeCode" />   <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="   Save   " />
  </form>
```

### employeeController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {
        employeeService.add(employee);
        return "employee";
    }
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/springsecurity-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

### Spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http security="none" pattern="/resources/**"/>
    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

When click submit button it returns error `

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

`
I gave POST method on both ftl and controller. Then why would this happen?

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: Can you show your web.xml?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps but I had the same problem.

You are using springSecurityFilterChain with CSRF protection. That means you have to send a token when you send a form via POST request. Try to add the next input to your form:

```
<input type="hidden"
name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: That fix one part of the probelm, but have you investigated why a missing CSRF Token results in a "405 Request method 'POST' not supported" instead of an 403?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I saw, the mentioned solutions didn't work for latest SpringSecurity. Instead of passing through with hidden you can also send it through the action URL like below:

```
<form method="post" action="doUpload?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It is because of spring security Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection. It blocks the url. So i added an extra field inside the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Now it is working properly.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster i haven't notice his answer. I found it before he post his answer. But Anyway now i accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
action="addEmployee"
```

with:

```
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addEmployee"
```

Unless you are using Spring 3.2

EDIT after seeing XML:

Try to move servlet-context.xml to your WEB-INF directory and rename it 'appServlet-context.xml'. Then remove the line:

```
/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml,
```

From the contextConfigLocation in your web.xml.

The convention is that the context xml file is named '[servlet-name]-context.xml' where [servlet-name] is the name of the DispatcherServlet.

Also try to add a '/' to your form action, so:

```
action="/addEmployee"
```

Comment: I am using spring version 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.and().csrf().disable();
```

another solution (but every form)

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```